# Open a record from wizard

Tags: odoo

I have created a wizard in odoo v8. from there I am selecting a record which is many2one field.

how to open a form view of that selected record in wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a action like,

suppose you have a models.Transient model like

```
class wiz(models.TransientModel):
    _name ='custom.wiz'

    man2one_field = fields.Many2one('co_model_name', 'CoModel')

    def open_wiz(self):
        return {
          'name': _('New Open Wizard'),
          'view_type': 'form',
          "view_mode": 'form',
          'res_model': 'model', 
          'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
          'domain': [('id', '=', self.man2one_field.id)],
          }
```